# Access artifact in release pipeline without downloading onto agent

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

The only thing I do in release pipeline is copying the build artifacts onto another server so I'd like to copy the artifact directly without downloading it onto the Release agent first.

At logs from download artifacts step i see:

```
2020-09-28T12:41:34.9678728Z Preparing to download artifact: Install
2020-09-28T12:41:34.9863144Z Artifact Type: FileShare
2020-09-28T12:41:34.9972486Z Downloading artifact from file share: \\myshare\...\Install
```

But I don't see that file share path in any of the variables in Initialize Job step.

Is there any way to enable "Skip download of artifacts" and be able to access that path in pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable "Skip download of artifacts":

You can find “Skip download of artifacts” option in your agent job.
[image]
2.  Access file share path in pipeline:

You can find the file share path from the download artifacts step but not from the Initialize Job step.
You can find this path when you add the source folder in Copy files task.
[image]

You can also find this path on the artifacts page of the build pipeline result.
[image]

Comment: When I click the 3 dots next to the Source Folder on the Copy Files task it displays my artifact, but when I select it it puts $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyArtifact in the field. $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) points to the agent's storage, not the share where the artifact is stored.

Comment: @karol.etrych Can you provide a screenshot of when you click the 3 dots next to the Source Folder? What is the configuration of your publish build artifact task?

Comment: @karol.etrych Please check the second screenshot in my answer. When you click on that triangle, can you see the same page as mine?